# problem with multiple versions of cmake

Tags: compiling

I am Installing Amber22 in Ubuntu 18.04 and i got the following error

**The source "/home/aparna/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FortranCInterface/CMakeLists.txt" does not match the source "/usr/local/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FortranCInterface/CMakeLists.txt" used to generate cache.  Re-run cmake with a different source directory.**

I realised that the problem is due to multiple versions of cmake installed.  The command `$which -a cmake` shows the below
/home/aparna/anaconda3/bin/cmake

/usr/local/bin/cmake

I tried to remove cmake using
`$sudo apt-get remove cmake` and got
Package 'cmake' is not installed, so not removed

I donot remember how i installed cmake 3.15, but cmake 3.24 was installed using pip. How can i get rid of this problem and install Amber

Comment: You do not know if it was install as an apt, or a snap or a flatpak or some other method. The way to remove a file is the reverse of how it was installed.

Comment: Alternatively, can i use ln to redirect cmake to new version.